# How do you make the whole body content full page and not just covering the 3/4 of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have this page : and the problem there is that there's a vacant space below the white part. what I want is to extend the upper contents the (sidebar-nav and the main- content) to be full page.

[image]

```
<section id="left-sidebar-panel">
    <div id="left-panel-content">
        <img id="pictureShadow" src="/assets/images/main-photo.jpg">
        <nav id="menu-links" >
            <ul class="inline-block">
                <li class="mb-4 mt-4 text-white">
                    <a href="/" class="text-3xl font-light flex" id="homePage">
                        @include("svgs.home")
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="text-white mb-4">
                    <a href="/blogs" class="text-3xl hover:text-3xl flex" id="blogsPage">
                        @include("svgs.post")
                        Blogs
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="text-white mb-4">
                    <a class="text-3xl mt-2 flex" href="/podcasts"  id="podcastsPage">
                        @include("svgs.microphone")
                        Podcasts
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="text-white mb-4">
                    <a class="text-3xl flex" href="/work">
                        @include("svgs.laptop")
                        Work
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="text-white mb-4">
                    <a class="text-3xl flex" href="/side-projects">
                        @include("svgs.projects")
                        Side Projects
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>


<p class="text-xl text-normal">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed consequatur praesentium aliquid unde, debitis sit vel velit distinctio eligendi, nesciunt illum totam ad repudiandae. Pariatur dolor totam omnis eos eius ab debitis reprehenderit dicta, quidem, deleniti? Natus consequatur eum vel voluptatem illum doloremque dolores, id voluptatibus quas nam officia cumque dolor in, nobis maiores alias. Repellendus molestias quia nisi voluptas est voluptate ab quam voluptatum! Atque sequi magnam et iure sunt molestias ipsum odit ad repellendus reprehenderit hic temporibus possimus, totam eligendi quas amet accusantium dolores quibusdam dolorem, corrupti placeat perspiciatis animi velit. Odit quisquam ipsum voluptate quibusdam, et, placeat iure dolorum, expedita quia soluta cupiditate. Dicta cupiditate neque minus excepturi consectetur et, exercitationem fugit at enim ex libero. Debitis, omnis modi harum quisquam. Dicta, est esse fuga dolor doloremque architecto velit magnam eos nesciunt et natus ullam quasi error, eligendi. Autem dolorum debitis reiciendis alias atque fugiat aperiam soluta?</p>
```

Comment: Increase the size ....of div tag which have side bar and white space page..else you can add you code. To easy to find solutions.

Comment: Create more content? There's likely not enough content to fill the page. Either that, or you've got some margins coming in to play. Either way, we can't know what is causing your specific problem unless you provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it -- your above code doesn't replicate the problem.